# Why is my face orientation moving while I orbit an object and how do I fix it?

Tags: modeling, faces

I am trying to model a transformer in Blender but the corners of my objects seem broken and deformed. I turned on face orientation and saw half of all faces were red. As a viewer of Blender Guru, I know that they need to be blue. When i orbit objects the colors change and I can't locate the red faces. How do i make all of them blue? I am still beginner and I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

[image]

[image: face orientation off(solid viewport)][image: Face orientation on with the same angle][image: Another angle, the red and blue changes]

Comment: Did you use a solidify modifier? Sometimes if you set the thickness really low, show face orientation, and look at the object from far away it can do this. It may also help if you post your blend file so I can take a look at it for myself.

Comment: I don't know how to attach a blender file. No modifiers used except mirror on the car and subdivision on the fists. Thx for responding

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/pbq0w7Oj

Comment: Did it work? Thankyou for helping me out

Comment: So after looking at it, I'm still not really sure what the problem is. I noticed the same problem when I added new objects to the scene, which led me to believe it isn't the _objects_ that are broken, the scene is. To fix it: just copy everything from your blend file with CTRL+C, and paste it into a new one with CTRL+V. Sorry I wasn't able to find the problem, but I hope I still helped.

Comment: Copying it got rid of the red. I didn't even know you could do that. Thank you so much for spending your time to help me out

Comment: Did you mirror your mesh in Edit Mode or did you use a mirror modifier? Using the Mirror Function in Edit Mode sometimes causes flipped normals, depending on the overall shape of your mesh.

Comment: I only used mirror modifier on the car. It not only affected the car, but every object. You can check out the blend file if you are interested.

Comment: Hey @cervidae :). This is a clipping distance issue, can be solved by switching to Ortho view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clipping distance starts *very* low, and Blender doesn't like it :).

- Either increase the *Clip Start* distance in *SideBar > View*
- or switch to Orthographic view through *View > Orthographic*

*Increase the Clip Start distance...*
[image]

*...or switch to Orthographic view*
[image]